# Error during memory allocation using calloc (Free Heap block XXX modified at YYY after it was freed)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory, memory-management

I need a series of buffers of type unsigned long long and these are my code lines used in allocation.

```
FAC_op_Buffer = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc(static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*FAC_N) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64)) );
SDC_op_Buffer = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc(static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*SDC_n) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64)) );

MSC_coder_h_lvl_1 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
MSC_coder_h_lvl_2 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
MSC_coder_h_lvl_3 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
MSC_coder_l_lvl_1 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
MSC_coder_l_lvl_2 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
MSC_coder_l_lvl_3 = static_cast<uint_64 *>( calloc( static_cast<uint_32>(ceil(static_cast<float>(2*(MSC_n1_n2[0] + MSC_n1_n2[1])) / 64.0) ), sizeof(uint_64) ) );
```

The variables "MSC_n1_n2", "FAC_N", "SDC_N" contains the number of bits to be allocated.
And uint_64 is just typedef of standard int found in stdint.

```
typedef uint64_t uint_64;
```

Now the problem is when it goes to the second line allocating for "MSC_coder_h_lvl_2". I get an error. - Windows triggered break point.....

HEAP: Free Heap block XXX modified at YYY after it was freed

The memory locations XXX and YYY keep changing every time. But it always points to another buffer which I have allocated earlier but not freed.

And if I hit continue, rest of the allocations happens without any problem. When I look at the memory window all the other allocated locations are initialized to zero like it is supposed to. Only the second statement fails which makes "MSC_coder_h_lvl_2" point at 0x0000000.

I am using calloc instead of new because I want the capability of re sizing this buffer.

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do not use `malloc` and the like in C++, don't even use `new[]`. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: And if you need help debugging your code, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: The thing is, if I cut out this allocation code and write it separately as SSCCE, it works fine. I don't know what else in my project is interfering with this.

Comment: Well, find out! We don't have a magic crystal ball that tells us either. (And you *really really* should be using `std::vector` and ***really really really*** should ***not*** use `calloc`.)

Comment: `I am using calloc instead of new because I want the capability of re sizing this buffer.`  Then use `std::vector`.  `Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.`  That "help" is called *debugging*.  You wanted to use dynamically allocated memory this way --- once you do that, expect to get these errors due to your code mismanaging pointers, dynamically allocated memory, etc.  That's the deal you make with C++ once you placed the responsibility of dynamic memory allocation on your shoulders.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I did not post this question expecting some magical answer from magical people! Posted it thinking if somebody else had a similar situation I might get some hint from them. When a question is posted it is not your 'burden' to answer them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes debugging!! I posted the question without trying anything!!

Comment: @Shreyes What apparently *is* too much of a burden for many people is reading the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which instructs you to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something that is still missing in your question. Finding people with the same problem like this is impossible because the code you posted does not even reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in my code. I was extremely stupid. The earlier buffer which this was clashing with was the problem. When I wrote data into that buffer I was exceeding its allocated size.

From this link http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=malloc#crash
Question 7.19 gave me an idea to check if I was exceeding the limit. 
It says that right after the allocated space malloc stores internal information such as size etc. When I wrote more than what I was supposed to, I destroyed this information.

Because of this when I was allocating a different buffer it was trying to allocate in this already used block but whose internal data I have partly destroyed.

I corrected this overrun problem and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

"it always points to another buffer which I have allocated earlier but not freed"

I'm willing to believe that you did not **intentionally** free it. But from experience I believe Visual C++ more than I believe you.

One quick way to verify this would be `#define free(X)` in a few suspect files. Sure, it's a 100% memory leak, but when the bug goes away you know located the file doing an incorrect `free` call.

Comment: For this project I have not written any exit methods yet. What I mean is I have not written any 'free' call yet. So I am pretty sure I have not freed that buffer. Besides this occurs amidst of calloc calls I don't understand why some write operation on a different buffer is happening. Moreover all the surrounding calloc returns valid pointers.